# Pass the error Message to XPage client from Java Server code

Tags: java, xpages

Here is my Java code, before call I call the `save()` method. I want to check this business rule.

```
   if (endDate.before(startDate)){
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "",
        "The end date should be not before the start date.");
        // Throw exception so that it prevents document from being saved
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.addMessage("travel_endDate",message);
        return false;

    }
```

I want this message display at the "travel_endDate" component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the client id of your component when adding the message.

1.) Add a binding to you component

```
<xp:inputText
    id="travel_endDate"
    binding="#{errorComponent}">
</xp:inputText>
```

2.) resolve the variable in your save method

```
UIComponent cmp = (UIComponent) facesContext.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(facesContext, "errorComponent");
String clientId = cmp.getClientId(facesContext);
```

3.) Add the message with the id to the facesContext

```
facesContext.addMessage(clientId,message);
```

Comment: I have DateField control with id="dateCtr" and input component with name="travel_endDate" also have binding binding="#{errorComponent}" like you said. 
from browser I got id is something like id="view:_id1:_id215:_id228:dateCtr" , but in the server I got "view:_id1:_id215:_id228", missing the parent control id.
How could i get this clientid with current component id plus parent control id?
thanks